# Render :partial a random object from DB by id, in custom form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I'm trying to render an random object from database.
Steps: 1. `generate button`(main page) -> 2. call `rand_task`(controller) -> 3. `_rand_show.html.erb` (form)

Problem:It crushes now, but one time it worked.(I know in  coding there isn't such thing but I can't manage  to see the problem...)
main:

```
<%= form_for(:task, :url => {:action =>'rand_task', :id => 'random'}) do |f|%>
<%= render(:partial => "rand_show", :locals => {:f => f}) %></p> 
<%end%>
```

controller:

```
def rand_task
  @task = Task.order('RANDOM()').first
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, :disabled=>true %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :category, :disabled=>true %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "generate"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Server:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-13 19:35:56 +0300
Processing by TasksController#main as HTML
  Rendered tasks/_rand_show.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered tasks/main.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
    1: <%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
    2:   <div class="field">
    3:     <%= f.label :name %><br />
    4:     <%= f.text_field :name, :disabled=>true %>
  app/views/tasks/_rand_show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_tasks__rand_show_html_erb__183960888__627313568'
  app/views/tasks/main.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_tasks_main_html_erb__298912262__627495408'
  app/views/tasks/main.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_tasks_main_html_erb__298912262__627495408'
```

**If I put a `<%= form_for(@task _=Task.new_ ) do |f| %>` than remove it it works but only  for once instance**

Answer (score 1):

This error is telling you that the @task object is nil in this case.  You need to make sure you have records in your "tasks" table.

Comment: i do have and still, that random method takes only from existing records.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: for local variables to acces you neeed to add the table to config/routes.rb in my case `resources :tasks`

edit: after server restart problem persists.