# call partial with object from query call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I've got a problem to get my partial working.

I want to pass an object via a local variable to a partial, but I get a

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

error all the time. But the variable is passed over because I can call it in the partial with .to_yaml, which gives me all the variables properties.

But when I try to use it in a form_for I get that error.

Maybe it has something to do with my db query. Because when i try to call it with another local variable there is no error. But my query should produce a single object, or am I wrong with that?

Here is my show.html.erb:

```
<%= @partneroffer = Partneroffer.where(:partner_id => @partner.id, :yearname_id => year.id).first  %>
<%= render :partial => "form2", :locals => { :partneroffer => @partneroffer } %>
```

And here is my partial (_form2.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for partneroffer , :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :partnerstatus_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:partnerstatus_id, Partnerstatus.all, :id, :name) %>
  <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
 partner_year_terms_path, :class => 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that in your partial, *partneroffer* is a nil object, so it doesn't have the method "model_name".

You are rendering the view the right way, and you are passing the locals the right way, however, are you sure that Partneroffer.where(:partner_id => @partner.id, :yearname_id => year.id).first is not getting a nil value? Try this code in show.html.erb:

```
<%- @partneroffer = Partneroffer.where(:partner_id => @partner.id, :yearname_id => year.id).first  %>
<%- if @partneroffer %>
  <%= render :partial => "form2", :locals => { :partneroffer => @partneroffer } %>
<%- else %>
   @partneroffer is nil!!!!
<%- end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That was indeed the cause. Found the solution myself a minute ago!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution based on one of the related topics ([Render :partial a random object from DB by id, in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411052/render-partial-a-random-object-from-db-by-id-in-custom-form?rq=1))! The problem was that I have to call the partial four times. But in only one case there was a record in my query results. Each time there wasn't a record rails threw this error message. I knew there was at least a result in one of the partial calls but wasn't aware that there has to be one in each result. Thx to [weexpectedthis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792445/weexpectedthis)!